# An incomplete or interdependent answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, review

[Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86230/45534) is an answer by jpe61 that was flagged as low quality. I strongly considered rejecting the flag, given the number of upvotes, until I looked at the question body. When I recommended deletion, he said

> @Abdullah this answer adresses the "What does "2-cycle oil" mean?" portion of the question. Other aspects of the Q are perfectly adressed by Federico's answer.

So the answer complements another answer, and answers (only) part of the question. So it *is* a useful answer, though *not* a complete one. What should happen to it?

Answer (score 6):

IMO that's an issue with the question (not the answer) since it has multiple elements. Stack Exchange is designed for focused questions.

---

To elaborate further, the title reads "What does this formulation mean?" -- which is very vague. I take its low vote-count after becoming a network-wide hot topic as confirmation to my viewpoint.

There are various ways it can be improved, but I don't see a way that would not invalidate the answers, nor is it really the topic at hand. In short, **the flagged answer is fine.**

Related on MSE: [Is it okay to put partial answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144452)